# Find the most frequent words in a file

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a file and I want to find the 10 most frequent words in that. I omitted stop words and punctuation and then put the result in a list. Each line contains a Persian sentence, a tab and then an English word. The problem is, the code below returns one word of each line. for example if the number of lines is 12, it returns 12 words. I think the indentation has problem. How can I fix it?

```
.
.
.
def train ():
    RemStopWords (file1, file2)  # the function for removing stop words and punctuation at the start of the code
    for line in witoutStops:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        words = line[0].split()
        uniques = []
        q = []
        for word in words:
            if word not in uniques:
                uniques.append(word)
        counts = []
        for unique in uniques:
            count = 0              
            for word in words:     
                if word == unique:   
                    count += 1         
            counts.append((count, unique))
            counts.sort()        
            counts.reverse()
            for i in range(min(10, len(counts))):
                count, word = counts[i]
            print('%s %d' % (word, count))
            #q.append(word)
            #print (q)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
from collections import Counter

def train ():
    RemStopWords (file1, file2)  # the function for removing stop words and punctuation at the start of the code
    counter = Counter()
    for line in withoutStops:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        words = line[0].split()
        counter.update(words)
    top10 = [word[0] for word in counter.most_common(10)]
    print(top10)
```

Comment: It works, but I need just the words. How can I append the words to a list. thanks

Comment: I've added that to my answer, sara

Answer (score 0):

A c++ based solution using priority queue, map and trie
Here is the similar c++ code using priority queue, map and trie. for simplicity its reading from vector strings but can be easily modified to read words from file.

Find the top K frequent words in a file or stream, C++
This is a working solution for priority_queue for your reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

#define K_TH 3


class TrieNode;
typedef struct HeapNode
{
    string word;
    int frequency;
    HeapNode(): frequency(0), word(""){} ;
    TrieNode *trieNode;

}HeapNode;


class TrieNode
{
    private:
        int frequency = 0;
        bool m_isLeaf = false;
        string word = "";
        unordered_map<char, TrieNode*> children;
        HeapNode *heapNode = NULL;

    public:
        TrieNode() {}
        TrieNode(char c)
        {
            children[c] = new TrieNode();
            this->m_isLeaf = false;
        }

        void setWord(string word)
        {
            this->word = word;
        }
        string getWord()
        {
            return this->word;
        }
        bool isLeaf(void)
        {
            return this->m_isLeaf;
        }
        void setLeaf(bool leaf)
        {
            this->m_isLeaf = leaf;
        }
        TrieNode* getChild(char c)
        {
            if (children[c] != NULL)
                return children[c];
            return NULL;
        }
        void insert(char c)
        {
            children[c] = new TrieNode();
        }
        int getFrequency()
        {
            return this->frequency;
        }
        void setFrequency(int frequency)
        {
            this->frequency = frequency;
        }
        void setHeapNode(HeapNode *heapNode)
        {
            this->heapNode = heapNode;
        }
        HeapNode* getHeapNode()
        {
            return heapNode;
        }
        bool operator()(HeapNode* &a, HeapNode* &b)
        {
            return (a->frequency > b->frequency);
        }
};

class Trie
{
    private:
        TrieNode *root = NULL;

    public:
        Trie()
        {
            if (!root)
            {
                this->root = new TrieNode();
            }
        }
        TrieNode* insert(string word)
        {
            if (!root)
                root = new TrieNode();
            TrieNode* current = root;
            int length = word.length();
            //insert "abc"
            for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                if (current->getChild(word.at(i)) == NULL)
                {
                    current->insert(word.at(i));
                }
                current = current->getChild(word.at(i));
            }
            current->setLeaf(true);
            current->setWord(word);
            current->setFrequency(current->getFrequency() + 1);
            return current;
        }
};



struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(HeapNode* &a, HeapNode* &b)
    {
        return (a->frequency > b->frequency);
    }
};
typedef priority_queue<HeapNode*, vector<HeapNode*>, cmp > MinHeap;


void insertUtils(Trie *root, MinHeap &pq, string word )
{
    if (!root)
        return;

    TrieNode* current = root->insert(word);
    HeapNode *heapNode = current->getHeapNode();
    if(heapNode)// if word already present in heap 
    {
        heapNode->frequency += 1;
    }else if (pq.empty() || pq.size() < K_TH)
    {// if word not present in heap and heap is not full;
        heapNode = new HeapNode();
        heapNode->word = word;
        heapNode->frequency = 1;
        heapNode->trieNode = current;
        current->setHeapNode(heapNode);
        pq.push(heapNode);
    }else if (pq.top()->frequency < current->getFrequency())
    {   // if word is not present and heap is full;
        HeapNode *temp = pq.top();
        //remove first element and add current word
        pq.pop();
        delete temp;
        heapNode = new HeapNode();
        current->setHeapNode(heapNode);
        pq.push(heapNode);
    }
}


void printKMostFrequentWords(vector<std::string> input)
{

    Trie *root = new Trie();
    MinHeap minHeap;
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
    {
        insertUtils(root, minHeap, *it);
    }

    while(!minHeap.empty())
    {
        HeapNode *heapNode = minHeap.top();
        cout << heapNode->word << ":" << heapNode->frequency << endl;
        minHeap.pop();
    }


}

int main() {

vector<std::string>input( {
    "abc", "def", "ghi",
    "jkl", "abc", "def",
    "mno", "xyz", "abc"

} ) ;
printKMostFrequentWords(input);
}
```